# Joomla 3 "Tag Selected" Not Showing TItle in Footer Position

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Site: http://bit.ly/13GerYd

I am using Joomla 3 with default Protostar template. I have created a "Tag Selected" module which just shows all pages with a specific tag. It works fine in the sidebar but for some reason when I position the module in the footer the TITLE does not appear. I have toggled Show/Hide title from the module and nothing. It's setup the same way as the ones in the blue sidebar area and I don't see it in the DOM so CSS is not hiding it.

Has anyone had this issue? The "Tag Selected" php template is below but I didn't want to edit this since the module works in other positions. Thoughts?

```
<?php JLoader::register('TagsHelperRoute', JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php'); ?>
<div class="tagsselected<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php if ($list) : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($list as $i => $item) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php $item->route = new JHelperRoute; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->content_item_id, $item->core_alias, $item->core_catid, $item->core_language, $item->type_alias, $item->router)); ?>">
                <?php if (!empty($item->core_title)) :
                    echo htmlspecialchars($item->core_title);
                endif; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else : ?>
    <span><?php echo JText::_('MOD_TAGS_SIMILAR_NO_MATCHING_TAGS'); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the module title does not show up in the footer if there were no style given to the footer modules. This solution is made in your template index.php file - Templates/YOURTEMPLATE/index.php:

in the fooer part there is a code like:
Code:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" />
```

Replace it with this following code,
Code:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" />
```